# How to change image's size? Image does not fill

Tags: swift, image, profile

I'm trying to make the image rounded. It is already 128x128 (width and height) and the corner radius is 64. I want to zoom in before cutting the photo to take the full rounded size of the picture.

[image: Example]

How to zoom it?

My code:

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 64
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

I want to make it like this:

[image: Borders are rounded here]

Comment: Put above line of code in Viewdidlayoutsubviews() method

Comment: Check the aspect ratio of the imageView is 1:1

Comment: I think the image you are using is horizontal. The rest of the part is just not visible due to the black background color. Try putting the border color to check.         
    profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

Comment: I have edited spelling and grammar; inlined screenshot. It would nice if you could resize your screenshot to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `UIImageView`'s content mode to `.scaleAspectFill`. That way, the image will fill up the whole container without distorting it.

```
profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 0):

please first ensure your image height and width must be equal. and constraint set properly

after that change below to line

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width/2
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: i get the same result its maybe image problem its an apple image

Comment: may be, but any time you can display circle image i requesting  you to use code like mine way because in different different device image size change at a time you can not set static ratio like = 64

Comment: guys my photo is rounded its just don't stick in the circle

Comment: your photo is rounded my image view not rounded bro