# can i force the user input in login or signup screen to be only in english

Tags: swift, firebase, user-input, sign, non-english

i'm traying to force the user input to be only in English so if the user sign up prevent the user from sign up with other language 
I don't know if firebase have already prevent the users from that behind the seen but if they didn't do that, is there any programmatic way in code , or this is not a really a problem in developing app and i'm just freaking out

```
func textField(_ textFieldToChange: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textFieldToChange == username {
        let characterSetNotAllowed = CharacterSet.whitespaces
        if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from:NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetters) {
            return false
        }
        if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSetNotAllowed, options: .caseInsensitive) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: What does it mean for someone’s name, for example, to be *”only in English”*, and why is that something you think you need to enforce? Should everyone be called John Smith?

Comment: you don't git it in full name text field let the user wright what he wants bu in username field its have to be in english like (John_Smith) so the people can search for you and add you  , now (John_Smith) can't be in any other language like (جون ـ سميث) you git it

Comment: do you know some way or you just asking ?!

Comment: @mazenqp you can prevent non English characters to be input into the text field

Comment: how is that by this method  or other method , i edit my question

Comment: Are you gonna allow digits also in your field?

Comment: yes no problem with numbers in username like ( Leo_Dabus22)

Comment: but can i prevent numbers from full name like ( Leo Dabus )

Comment: You can crete a custom CharacterSet and use that to filter the string input

Comment: if i do know how to do that i wouldn't ask

Comment: kkkk I will post

Comment: let characterSetNotAllowed = CharacterSet.whitespaces

Comment: So you mean *”only using a-z and underscores”*, not *”only in English”*? In that case of course Swift supports input validation, you can define e.g. a regex that should apply.

Comment: @mazenqp I have noticed that you have made already a lot of questions but haven't accepted any of them. There is a check mark below the votes counter that you should use to mark an answer as correct if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start subclassing UITextField and add a target for editing changed [UIControlEvents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents) and filter your the string entered by the user when it changes:

```
class EnglishLettersField: UITextField {
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        editingChanged(self)
    }
    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text?.englishLetters else { return }
        textField.text = text
    }
}
extension CharacterSet {
    // create your own set with the allowed characters to filter your string
    static let englishLetters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ")
}

extension String {
    // create a computed property to separate the original text using the custom character set inverted, join it again and return it
    var englishLetters: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.englishLetters.inverted).joined()
    }
}
```

---

You can add it programatically to your view or using the interface builder

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let englishLettersField = EnglishLettersField(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)))
        view.addSubview(englishLettersField)
    }
}
```

[sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eagait6t4sds4vg/English%20Letters%20Field.zip?dl=1)

Comment: sorry i have already text Field in storyboard not in code when i said programmatic i was mean in code not the textfields but the code to make the english language

Comment: click on it and change it in the inspector to EnglishLettersField

Comment: @mazenqp again you should go to your old questions and accept the correct answers like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921045/2303865

Comment: i will accept this you mean by click this ✅ button but i don't get this answer right this is a long method and I know in programing there is a lot of ways to do something anything easier like another code to do that like that method in my question

Comment: Yes you can do it also using a delegate and filtering the text inside that method. And you can also change the accepted answer at anytime

Comment: But subclassing it is a much better/concise approach as you can use it multiple times in your code without the need to add extra code to your view controller. You should read about decoupling

Comment: You can also answer your own question. You should roll back your question to the original format
.

Comment: Btw you should use CharacterSet when coding in Swift 3 or later

Comment: @mazenqp check this sample project https://www.dropbox.com/s/eagait6t4sds4vg/English%20Letters%20Field.zip?dl=1

Comment: look thanks but i cant inherent from class i already inheriting from another class called UITextFieldEffects i implemented this pod from githup

Comment: @mazenqp you can easily add those methods to any class that is a subclass of UITextField. If it already implements `willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {` just add those two lines there and add the editChanged method also to it and the extensions to the bottom of that file.

Comment: your method is to hard to understand i'm new to programing and i cant get it   i don't want you to solve my problem but can you just give me a simple code rather than wright all that code

Comment: something else i don't know how to deal with Subview and i don't get a lot of things to do 1 simple task

Comment: how can attach this method to IBoutlet like usernameTextField IBOutlet don't give me extensions